# Unable to download multiple files from SharePoint to my C drive

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How to download multiple files in one process from SharePoint to my download folder

Comment: which version of sharepoint? you can sync a library on Sharepoint 2013 and later....

Answer (score 9):

The only way that normal user can download multiple files from SP interface is through "Open With Explorer" in IE. However, there's another backdoor way that user can map the library to disk that will open SharePoint Library as open a folder.

Click Computer > Map network drive > Connect to a website > Choose a network location, then paste the library URL.

Be aware of that since you can see the backdoor of SharePoint, don't delete any folders. Otherwise, that can cause serious consequence.

Comment: Perfect answer, but be careful Yoga reminder. This can lost all of your data.

Answer (score 7):

The only way you can download multiple files from SharePoint is by using "Open With Explorer" and it only works in IE.

- List Navigate to the document library you want to download files
- Click The Library option (from the ribbon)
- Click on Open With Explorer
- Wait couple of seconds (sometimes, it takes up to 10 secs or so to open the Windows explorer)
- Once Windows Explorer open, you can select one or more files to copy to your local drive

[image]